# magento custom layout for product detail page

Tags: php, magento

i want to design custom deign layout page

i take help from 1page-left-layout.xml

i get idea about left sidebar else now i want to chnage postion of price, media, attributes and all where can i get hint , i see there is only one function there

```
echo $helper->getModulesByPosition('content')
```

how to break it to get media price and other as seprate units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/custom.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```